# Overloading assignment and plus operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    int i;
    string s;

    public:
    test(){}

    test(int a,string b)
    {
        i=a;
        s=b;
    }

    void operator = (test &temp)
    {
        cout<<"In assignment operator"<<endl;
        i=temp.i;
        s=temp.s;
    }

    test  operator + (test &temp)
    {
        test newobj;
        newobj.i=i+temp.i;
        newobj.s=s+" "+temp.s;
        return newobj;
    }
};

main()
{
    test t1(5,"ABC");
    test t2;
    t2=t1;
    test t3;
    t3=t1+t2;
}
```

Question : `t3=t1+t2` gives me an error. I want to overload both = and + operators and use them as shown above. Where am I wrong ? I want to explicitly define one assignment operator overload even though one is provided by compiler.

> error : invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘test&’ from an rvalue of type ‘`test`’ `t3=t1+t2;`
>
> initializing argument 1 of ‘`void test::operator=(test&)`’
>       `void operator = (test &temp)`

Comment: Both operators should take their argument as `const test&`.

Comment: The params need to be `const temp &`; since `t1 + t2` makes a temporary and can't be passed through a non-const.

Comment: Would really appreciate if someone could explain the use of const in parameter. As far as I understand, const just indicates that data members of the object recieved can not be changed. I might be wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t1+t2` returns a temporary `test`, which can't be bound to reference to non-const (i.e. `test &`), that's why `t3=t1+t2;` fails. On the other hand, temporary could be bound to reference to const (i.e. `const test&`). So you can change the parameter type to `const test&`, e.g.

```
void operator = (const test &temp)
{
    cout<<"In assignment operator"<<endl;
    i=temp.i;
    s=temp.s;
}
```

BTW1: It's better to do the same thing with `operator+`.

BTW2: The conventional signature (and implementation) of `operator=` is:

```
test& operator= (const test& temp)
{
    cout<<"In assignment operator"<<endl;
    i = temp.i;
    s = temp.s;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But did not understand your explanation regarding const. By receiving test object as const, how does the above code works just well ?  In assignment operator overload function, why do we need to return current object when we are just assigning values from second object to the current object. Say t2=t1, here t2 object will invoke = operator and will receive reference of t1 object. Then we are just assigning the values of t1 to t2. Why do we need to return *this  ? (i.e. reference to object t2)

Comment: @DigeshPatel Because temporary can't be bound to `test&`, but `const test&`. e.g. `test& t = test{};` would fail, but `const test& t = test{};` is fine.

Comment: @DigeshPatel For your 2nd question, that makes it possible to chain the operators like built-in types. e.g. `t1 = t2 = t3;`.